# can it be said that $ a<a $ where a is a real?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

can it be said that $a<a $ where a is a real number? i think so but i wanna clarify.i had a fight over this with a junior who thinks otherwise. what does "or" mean in the law of trichotomy.I may be wrong.But I remember being told by a teacher.
I think so because in case of sets A can be said be a subset of A.

Comment: No, the answer is no. The notation $x<y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ means: $x$ is strictly less than $y$. But $a\leq a$ is true.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's possible?

Comment: @DSeita : It is a common programmer problem with meaning of "or". consider x=0, then (x<1 or x>-1) is true to programmer. now consider x must be less than 1 or x must be greater than -1, then there is no number that fits the 2nd criteria of usual language usage of "or".

Comment: @Arjang I'm sorry I still don't get it. In my programming, 'or' has always meant either A or B or both are true. And I'm still not sure how this relates with $a < a$.

Comment: @DSeita : so consider it to the law of trichotomy, then you can have more than one of the criteria being true, where only one criteria can be true. There are 3 mutually exclusive cases, it really has something to do with misinterpretation of meaning, the confusion that arises is not based on logical understanding, having suffered the same problem I can understand the op's problem. If you don't get then that only means you are logically better wired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Or" is often a confusing word for people first encountering it in mathematics, as much of the time it means something different from the colloquial use of "or." Mathematically, $X$ or $Y$  means "either $X$ or $Y$ or both," unless more information is given. The statement of trichotomy *does not* use or in this way: we have a slightly different statement.

**Trichotomy:** For any two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, *exactly one* of the following is true:

1. $a < b$
2. $b < a$
3. $a = b$.

Taking your two numbers to be the same, we find that since $a = a$, $a\not< a$ and $a\not > a$. The "exactly one" part of this statement is the reason you cannot have $a < a$.